Is there a way I can pull linked issues from a type in jira using filters?
I am using a filter in jira  as below
project = ENG-123 AND type IN (SRE) ORDER BY Rank ASC
so in the given project I am creating an epic and then a type SRE, later I create subtask under the type SRE ,so I want to get type SRE and all the linked sub-tasks.
I am not able to figure out way to do so. any support or advise is much appretiated
